# How to convert docx base64 encoded stream to PDFA base64 encoded stream

Tags: java, docx4j

I am using docx4j to convert docx to PDF (which reads and writes file into a path).
But is it possible to convert the base64 encoded docx stream to base64 encoded PDF/A stream.
I don't want to write the file.

[Docx encoded file](https://spaces.hightail.com/receive/Rli5sR1KbB)

```
String wordDocFile="C:\\Pega\\PRPCPersonalEdition\\tomcat\\temp\\A simple word doc to reduce the PDF load.docx";               
 String pdfDocFile="C:\\Pega\\PRPCPersonalEdition\\tomcat\\temp\\Doc_to_PDF.pdf";              
 InputStream is = new FileInputStream(wordDocFile);
 OutputStream  out= new FileOutputStream(new File (pdfDocFile));
 WordprocessingMLPackage pack = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(is);
 Docx4J.toPDF(pack, out);
 out.close();
 is.close();
```

Comment: Which convert to PDF tech are you using?  I expect you'll need to decode your base64, but probably no need to write a file.

Comment: @JasonPlutext Added the code snippet which i am using in my tool . Opening the docx and generating from defined path works. But usecase i am trying is, i will have base64 encoded of a docx file and i need to return base64 encoded PDFA

Comment: Do you have docx4j-export-fo or docx4j-documents4j-local|remote on your classpath? (the Microsoft Graph approach can't be invoked that way)

Comment: @JasonPlutext Yes all the necessary jars are there and its working. I have included a sample input file (Encoded). 
Need to convert that encoded data into PDFA encoded

Comment: I wanted to know which of those jars are there, in order to understand which underlying tech you are using.  But no matter, you are feeding it an InputStream.  Use a ByteArrayInputStream instead of a FileInputStream.